# clearInterval inside setInterval, unable to break loop, with jquery and .post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, clearinterval

I'm trying to call clearInterval inside setInterval function, which is doing some ajax fetching, without any luck.

```
var nre = setInterval('checkit()',5000);
$(function() {
    checkit = function(){
        $.post("check.php", { login: "<?php echo $_SESSION['login'];?>" }, function( data ) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#debug').html(data);
                window.clearInterval(nre);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

The point is, that the loop wont break, although recieves positive data to do so.

I've read that async action of setInterval function might be the issue here. Is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: First of all, change to: `var nre = setInterval(SANAjax,5000);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move everything inside the same scope, and don't use the string form of `setInterval`:

```
$(function() {
    var nre = setInterval(checkit, 5000);
    function checkit() {
        $.post("check.php", { login: "..." }, function( data ) {
            if (data === 1) {
                $('#debug').html(data);
                clearInterval(nre);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, athough with "==" operator.

Comment: @PiotrC ah, so your `data` isn't actually exactly `1` ?

Comment: Well, with what I can see it's very 1

Answer (score 2):

checkit won't be visible outside the `document.ready` so move the `setInterval` call inside the `document.ready`.

If you would like to assign an anonymous function to the variable checkit, then you will have to move the setInterval call after the variable is assigned.

```
$(function() {
    var checkit = function(){
        $.post("check.php", { login: "<?php echo $_SESSION['login'];?>" }, function( data ) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#debug').html(data);
                window.clearInterval(nre);
            }

        });
    }
   var nre = setInterval(checkit,5000);
});
```

Or, if you declare the function, then you can call `setInterval` before the function declaration.

```
$(function() {
    var nre = setInterval(checkit, 5000);
    function checkit() {
        $.post("check.php", { login: "..." }, function( data ) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('#debug').html(data);
                clearInterval(nre);
            }
        });
    }
});
```