# Refresh element including attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh, intervals

I would like to refresh a `<data>` element every second incuding it's attributes:

```
<data id="one" data-status="offline"></data>
```

I tried to use the `.load()` method:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(#one).load(page.php #one, function() {
        if($(#one).data("status") == "online"){
            alert("online!");
            return false; //stop interval(?)
        } else {
            alert("offline!");
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

but its not working properly.

The main problem is that the  element is refreshed as a child like this:

```
 <data id="one" data-status="offline"><data id="one" data-status="online"></data></data>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: refer this answer is doing same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280997/clearinterval-inside-setinterval-unable-to-break-loop-with-jquery-and-post

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
document.getElementById('one').reload();
```

might work...